# Tensorflow reading a tab separated file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to read a tab separated file into tensorflow

```
# Metadata describing the text columns
COLUMNS = ['queue_name','block_name', 'car_name',
           'position_id', 'x_ord',
           'y_ord']
FIELD_DEFAULTS = [[''], [''], [''], [0], [0], [0]]
def _parse_line(line):
    # Decode the line into its fields
    fields = tf.decode_csv(line, FIELD_DEFAULTS, field_delim="\t")

    # Pack the result into a dictionary
    features = dict(zip(COLUMNS,fields))

    # Separate the label from the features
    y = features.pop('y_ord')
    x = features.pop('x_ord')

    return features, x, y


ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames).skip(1)
ds = ds.map(_parse_line)
with tf.Session() as sess:
print(sess.run(ds)) # I am getting an error when running the session
```

However, this gives me an error 

`TypeError: Fetch argument <MapDataset shapes: ({period_name: (), block_name: (), trial_name: (), trial_id: ()}, (), ()), types: ({period_name: tf.string, block_name: tf.string, trial_name: tf.string, trial_id: tf.int32}, tf.int32, tf.int32)> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a MapDataset into a Tensor or Operation.)`

Does this mean I cannot combine string and integers in a map dataset or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error for?

Comment: I am getting an error when running a session on the graph, I am not sure how to check if my data has been read in correctly and the documentation doesn't detail such aspects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because you are trying to run something that is not a Tensor or an Operation but a Dataset object. You can create a tensor from the Dataset object such that everytime you run it, you get the next sample from your dataset.

Try the following:

```
value = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
print(sess.run(value)) # First value in your dataset
print(sess.run(value)) # Second value in your dataset
```

Building up from here, you can construct rest of your model from this tensor.

See the docs at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator

Comment: ahh that example page needs someone to clarify the semantics and add this statement

Comment: perhaps - i'm glad you got things figured out :)